# How does DispatcherServlet work if we have multiple XML Configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, architecture

**Questions**

*How does DispatcherServlet work if we have multiple XML Configuration file so how does Spring Application Context loads them and acts on them ?*

**Scenario:**

In my case, we have an application that is supposed to global that is application should have `AP{Asia-Pacific}, EM{Europ-Middleeast}, CA{Canada} and LA{Latin America}` Versions.

Currently, we have Application for one region that is `EM`and its has its `XML Configuration File i.e, em-servelt.xml` and then there is generic `web.xml` file now for `AP region` we have another `ap-servlet.xml` file and by the way both `em-servlet.xml` and `ap-servlet.xml file` would have same bean names but they would be pointing to Controllers in different packages, so for example, em would be pointing to something like `com.em.DomainController` and ap would be pointing to `com.ap.DomainController`.

So my question is

***How is the request mapped to different controllers and how request is being recognized so that it should read from ap-servlet.xml or em-servlet.xml ?***

I hope am able to clearly state my question.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question ?

Comment: It's not very clear. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to have several `DispatcherServlet`s at once, or what?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `web.xml` file can configure multiple `DispatcherServlet` instances, each having its own configuration.  Each `DispatcherServlet` instance configures a `WebApplicationContext` separate from other `DispatcherServlet` instances, so you can use the same bean names without affecting the other application context.

```xml
<!-- configured by WEB-INF/ap-servlet.xml -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- configured by WEB-INF/em-servlet.xml -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>em</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

You must also configure `web.xml` to map requests to the appropriate `DispatcherServlet`.  For example, each region could have a different URL path.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ap</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ap/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>em</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/em/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `web.xml` file controls which context file DispatcherServlet is using. If you configure `web.xml` to have a `DispatcherServlet` with name `em`, then by default it uses `em-servlet.xml` to load the web context.

Your question is a bit confusing as to what you would actually like to do - do you want all "versions" to be available in the same instance of the application?

If so, the method you describe sounds unorthodox for how to present multiple languages / globalizing your application. Traditionally you would just have a single instance of the application and all the controllers/instances, and then handle translating user-visible messages at the display level. Spring has excellent support for this.

If your goal is to have a single instance of the application serve requests for all these languages/locales, then it sounds like you could do away with a lot of this redundancy.

Comment: I want to have all "versions" to be available in the same instance of the application?

Comment: Also different Region has different business logic and so we cannot do that at the display level